# Mac logic Recording problem

Tags: logic-pro

A red bar that labels itself as auto punch has showed up at the top of my main window. It prevents me from recording starting at the play head thumb when pressing R. Where would I find the option to revert back to original settings?[image: The red recording section above the Play thumb at the top right corner of the screen]

Answer (score 2):

Hm, you might check out this video. He addresses autopunch around 6:00

Comment: Maybe I press a hot key by mistake.